# Reserve Port in WebSphere

Tags: spring, websphere

I am using Spring with WebSphere 6.1 and today I started to get NET_BIND errors stating that port 1099 (port that Spring is using) is already in use and that Spring cannot use it.  I've been using that port for a long time and ran netat to make sure that 1099 wasn't listed (which it wasn't).  I also looked at the ports configured for my websphere server and 1099 wasn't listed there either.  So my question is:

1)  How do I figure out what is using port 1099
2)  How do I reserve 1099 so that WebSphere doesn't use port 1099?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I figure out what is using port 1099

I'm not sure which OS you are on, but on Windows XP -- 'netstat -b' will list the PID for each listener. Use that information to determine which process is using the port in question.

> 2) How do I reserve 1099 so that WebSphere doesn't use port 1099?

The only way WebSphere will use the port 1099 is if it is configured to do so (check your serverindex.xml files) or if that port falls within the [ephemeral range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html). I know the ephemeral range on XP starts at 1024, but you should be okay with most (all) flavors of Linux.